# How can I validate a structure member?

Tags: c, validation, structure, scanf

I need to validate the `bookid` member of a structure. This code is related to library management code... I need to validate all inputs taken from the user. All the inputs, like the author name and book details should be included.

```
struct
{
  int bid;
  char bname[25];
  char author[25];
  int nooftitles;
  char titles[500];
  int status;
}book;

void Addbook()
{
    int i; book.status=IN;

    // Opening the librecord file
    librecord = fopen("librecord.txt", "a+");

    // Need to validate below member
    printf("Enter The uniqueid of The Book: (Integer) \n");
    scanf("%d", &book.bid);

    printf("Enter The Name of The Book: \n");
    scanf("%s", book.bname);

    printf("Enter The Name of Author: \n");
    scanf("%s", book.author);

    printf("Enter The Number of Titles Of The Book: (Integer)\n");
    scanf("%d", &book.nooftitles);

    fprintf(librecord, "\n%d\t%s\t%s\t%d\t%d\t", book.bid, book.bname, book.author, book.status, book.nooftitles);
    printf("Enter The Titles Of The Book: \n");
    for(i=0; i<book.nooftitles; i++)
    {
        scanf("%s", book.titles);
        fprintf(librecord, "%s\t", book.titles);
    }
    fclose(librecord);
    printf(" (' ' ) A New Book has been Added Successfully...\n");
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by `validate `?

Comment: And what did you try? Iin particular, what does "valid" mean for you, and what code did you try to write to implement that?

Comment: What do you mean by validate? Verify that the input is a number? Verify that the number is unique? You should also change the question title, because it has nothing to do with structure members per se.

Comment: You know that by using `scanf("%s", ...)` you are restricted to single-word input, don't you? With book titles and autor names, that's very likely not what you want. You are also not adding books, you are modifying the only existing book.

Answer (score 1):

To validate the *inputs* (*primarily*), you need to take care of two major things,

1. check the return value of [`scanf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) whether it matches with the exact number of items it is *supposed* to scan.

   Example:

   ```
    if ( scanf("%d",&book.bid) != 1)
    {
       //error handling
    }
   ```
2. use the length modifier with `%s` to avoid the possibility of buffer overrun.

   Example: For

   ```
   char bname[25] ;
   ```

   use

   ```
   scanf("%24s",book.bname);
   ```

That said, as mentioned in the comments by  [M Oehm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2979617/m-oehm), if you want *space separated words* as input, `%s` won't work. Then you need to use [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) to read and store the input.